How can I tell Entity Framework to modify an array related entities?
I have an abstract AuditObject class with audit fields I can set automatically before saving changes on my entities.
public abstract class AuditObject
{
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}

In my DbContext before saving I set the audit fields:
 private void OnBeforeSaving()
 {
       var user = _someService.GetUserName();

       foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries()) 
       {
           if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified && entry.Entity is AuditObject auditObject) 
           {
               auditObject.UpdatedBy = user;
               entry.Property("CreatedBy").IsModified = false; 
           }
           else if (entry.State == EntityState.Added && entry.Entity is AuditObject auditObject)
           {
               auditObject.CreatedBy = user;
               auditObject.UpdatedBy = user;
           }
       }
 }

I inherit that on an entity I have with related entities as well:
public abstract class Order: AuditObject
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public List<OrderProducts> Products { get; set; }
}

public abstract class OrderProducts: AuditObject
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

Now when I receive the updated Order on my endpoint I set the Products list to the updated list.
[HttpPut("{id:long}")]
public async Task<Order> UpdateOrder(long id, Order order)
{
    var currentOrder = await _dbContext.Order
        .Include(x => x.Products)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == order.Id);

    currentOrder.Products = order.Products;
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok(currentOrder);
}

When I debug through the change tracker entries Entity Framework believes there was a modified and deleted state and results in creating new records for the Products. So if I have an existing Order with 1 product with Id 1, the first change tracker entry it sees that OrderProduct 1 was modified, and sets the UpdatedBy and flags the CreatedBy as not modified. Then it has a change tracker entry of key 1 being deleted. The end result is I get an exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: The property
'OrderProduct.CreatedBy' cannot be
assigned a value generated by the database. Store-generated values can
only be assigned to properties configured to use store-generated
values.

On initial creation there is never an issue, the CreatedBy and UpdatedBy get set and a new OrderProduct record is created. It is only when I am updating the list of products with existing product Ids. Is there a way I can tell Entity Framework when assigning the list of products to not consider an update both a modify and delete?

Completely Unrelated: it's very odd to audit by storing the name of the user instead of their id unless name is an alternate key.

This isn't the proper way to reassign related entities:
var currentOrder = await _dbContext.Order
    .Include(x => x.Products)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == order.Id);

currentOrder.Products = order.Products;

To avoid issues like this, start by protecting any/all collection setters to help ensure these types of operations don't come up in the future:
public List<OrderProducts> Products { get; protected set; } = new List<OrderProducts>();

It's a good idea to initialize the collection so if we create a new Order the Products collection is good to go. This applies only to collections of navigation properties, not singular ones.
Now when it comes to updating the products associated to an order, behind the scenes there is a linking table called something like OrderProducts where linking records are inserted and deleted to reflect the associations between orders and products. We never want to re-initialize a collection of one-to-many or many-to-many relationships. EF will be "listening" on the collection for items being added and removed, we don't want to break that connection by initializing a new List. Instead, we remove what needs to be removed and add what needs to be added. When it comes to adding, it is important that for association relations like many-to-many, you add references to entities that are tracked by the DbContext. In your case the order.Products passed into the method are not necessarily tracked by the DbContext instance you will be loading the current Order record from and updating so we should not explicitly add those detached instances to the loaded Order. If the DbContext isn't tracking them it will treat them as new entities. (Products, not OrderProduct records)  Because of this, we don't need to have methods that accept entire untracked product entities, we could just pass a collection of product Ids.
However, given the current code with a detached order and products, the simple way to do this:
[HttpPut("{id:long}")]
public async Task<Order> UpdateOrder(long id, Order order)
{
    var currentOrder = await _dbContext.Order
        .Include(x => x.Products)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == order.Id);

    var currentProductIds = currentOrder.Products.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
    var updatedProductIds = order.Products.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
    var productIdsToRemove = updatedProductIds.Except(currentProductIds);
    var productIdsToAdd = currentProductIds.Except(updatedProductIds);

    if (productIdsToRemove.Any())
    {
        foreach(var productId in productIdsToRemove)
        {
             var product = currentOrder.Products.First(x => x.Id == productId);
             currentOrder.Products.Remove(product);
        }
    }
    if (productIdsToAdd.Any())
    {
        var productsToAdd = await _dbContext.Products.Where(x => productIdsToAdd.Contains(x.Id)).ToListAsync();
        foreach(var product in productsToAdd)
            currentOrder.Products.Add(product);
    }

    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok(currentOrder);
}

Basically determine what items need to be removed and what need to be added. For items to remove, find them in the current order and remove them. For items to be added, load a reference from the DbContext and associate it.  You can avoid the round trip to the DbContext to get the items to add, but it's typically not worth the effort. That would look like:
    // ...

    if (productIdsToAdd.Any())
    {
        foreach(var productId in productIdsToAdd)
        {
            var existingProduct = _dbContext.Products.Local.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == productId); // Check the dbContext tracking cache for the product. Does not hit DB.
            if (existingProduct == null)
            {
                existingProduct = order.Products.First(x => x.Id == productId); // our detached product
                _dbContext.Attach(existingProduct);
            }
                
            currentOrder.Products.Add(existingProduct);
        }
    }

Basically what that does is for the product IDs to add, we check the DbContext for an already tracked instance. If we find one, we add it to the currentOrder.Products. If we don't then we can attach the current untracked one, then add it.  If we just called Attach on the order.Products it could work most of the time, but if the DbContext happened to already be tracking a product with the same ID you would get an exception. This manifests as situational runtime exceptions which can be difficult to reproduce. The advantage of this approach is that it avoids a DB round trip to get the products. The disadvantage / limitation is that it assumes that the detached product entities are complete, valid, and up to date. In many cases these items are deserialized and don't represent complete entities so attaching them can lead to odd issues like missing fields when a future query tries to read a Product and the DbContext hands back this incomplete tracked reference rather than a fresh entity loaded from the database.

This is a very detailed answer, thank you for that! This seems incredibly cumbersome the more layers of nested collections you have, as well as if existing items in the collection have modifiable properties. I will try looking for some generic solutions that might be re-useable.

Especially with web applications I find it is easier to manage things with more atomic operations rather than sending entire aggregates back and forth. It can be risky from a tampering perspective, stale data, or bugs, as well as expensive for the amount of data sent over the line, to send detached entities with relations.
